# php mail() from localhost

Tags: postfix, php5, localhost

I have installed both postfix and mailx, I also tried sendmail. I'm trying to send e-mail from a PHP script using a crontab. The crontab and PHP run fine but the mail won't send I get the following error in the mail.log

> Jul 31 21:32:31 grimlin sm-mta[19452]: o710Mcgq013215: o714VGcZ019452: sender notify: Warning: could not send message for past 4 hours
>   Jul 31 21:32:31 grimlin sm-mta[19452]: o714VGcZ019452: to=, delay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=30000, dsn=4.4.3, stat=queued
>   Jul 31 21:32:32 grimlin sm-mta[19452]: o710PicY013254: to=, ctladdr= (33/33), delay=04:05:53, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=2370465, relay=gmail.com., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Name server: gmail.com.: host name lookup failure
>   Jul 31 21:32:32 grimlin sm-mta[19452]: o710PicY013254: o714VGca019452: sender notify: Warning: could not send message for past 4 hours
>   Jul 31 21:32:32 grimlin sm-mta[19452]: o714VGca019452: to=, delay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=30000, dsn=4.4.3, stat=queued
>   Jul 31 21:40:01 grimlin postfix/postdrop[19713]: warning: unable to look up public/pickup: No such file or directory

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 (actually Mint 
I think i have main.cf setup right but I've never installed it so any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix your DNS first your server is unable to do DNS lookups.

```
stat=Deferred: Name server: gmail.com.: host name lookup failure
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks it's DNS problem.  Can you use dig to check the DNS?

```
dig mx yourdomain.com
```

> Name server: gmail.com.: host name
>   lookup failure

Comment: There are no domains associated with the account just my local ip and localhost. Is this the problem?

Comment: No. When people say that there is a problem with your DNS, they mean that your server cannot *resolve* any name. Post the contents of your /etc/resolv.conf